# python 3 Tkinter ComboBox don't get value

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, combobox, ttk

I am trying to get the value of from a combobox in tkinter using python 3.6, i been looking to many tutorials but i don't see the problem yet.
every time i press the button don't show anything.
but also there is not errors.
so to clarify ... I am trying to get the value of the tk.combobox when i press ttk.Button.
thank you in advance for any ideas or comments.
this is what i have so far.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


def combo_box_updater():
    total_location = ['linden', 'mineola', 'brooklyn']
    return total_location


def start_analisys(event=None):
    site = jobsite_name.get()
    print(site)


# this is part of a definition that automatically will update the names in later versions
job_site = combo_box_updater()


#  basic gui setup
unified = tk.Toplevel()
unified.title('Unified 1 Week Timesheet')
unified.configure(background="#00012f")
unified.geometry("650x200")
unified.resizable(width=False, height=False)
entry_width = 30


#  basic frame
frame1 = tk.Frame(unified)
frame1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='w')


#  combo box in the fourth row
jobsite_name = tk.StringVar()
combo_box = ttk.Combobox(frame1, font="none 12 bold", width=20, textvariable=jobsite_name, text="choose location")
combo_box.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="wesn")
combo_box['values'] = [x for x in job_site]

#  Left button side
ttk.Button(frame1, text='Run', command=start_analisys, ).grid(row=0, column=2, sticky='nsew', rowspan=3)

unified.mainloop()
```

Comment: The setup is a bit strange when I run your code, but I can see the values being printed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Made three minor edits to your code: added a label to display the result, added a line to combo box setup, and changed the creation of the main window.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


def combo_box_updater():
    total_location = ['linden', 'mineola', 'brooklyn']
    return total_location


def start_analisys(event=None):
    site = jobsite_name.get()
    aLabel["text"] = site
    print(site)


# this is part of a definition that automatically will update the names in later versions
job_site = combo_box_updater()


#  basic gui setup
unified = tk.Tk()
unified.title('Unified 1 Week Timesheet')
unified.configure(background="#00012f")
unified.geometry("650x200")
unified.resizable(width=False, height=False)
entry_width = 30


#  basic frame
frame1 = tk.Frame(unified)
frame1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='w')


#  combo box in the fourth row
jobsite_name = tk.StringVar()
combo_box = ttk.Combobox(frame1, font="none 12 bold", width=20, textvariable=jobsite_name)
combo_box.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="wesn")
combo_box['values'] = [x for x in job_site]
combo_box.current(0)
#  Left button side
ttk.Button(frame1, text='Run', command=start_analisys, ).grid(row=0, column=2, sticky='nsew', rowspan=3)

# add a label
aLabel = ttk.Label(frame1, text='My Label')
# place the label
aLabel.grid(column=3, row=0)


unified.mainloop()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    pass
```

Comment: im still analyzing your code but it work beautifully. thank you very much

Comment: No problem Caser Rodriguex. If you have any questions let me know.

Answer (score 0):

When you add the values as an afterthought like that you need to add the corresponding commands as well. It's much better to add the values through the init method so the commands are automatically added:

```
jobsite_name = tk.StringVar(value="choose location")
combo_box = ttk.Combobox(frame1, textvariable=jobsite_name, values=job_site, font="none 12 bold", width=20)
```

Comment: thank you Novel for you answer, but i found that the only thing that prints is "choose Location", how you make it get the value of the drop box. I'm new to python and tkinter .